# how to dismiss a reminder after sending a recurring email via vba?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, reminder

I was able to create a recurring email via a code in vba that triggers every time that a reminder with a certain category fires.

http://www.slipstick.com/developer/send-email-outlook-reminders-fires/

My question, is how do I dismiss the reminder after the email is send?
when I add the line reminders(1).Dismiss the code breaks at that point.

if I continue with the execution of the reminder finally appears in outlook.

It appears that the application reminders macro needs to finish to be executed in order to dismiss reminder event.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN  the [`Applcation.Reminder` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870058.aspx) used Slipstick's macros is executed *before* the reminders dialog appears. But the [`Reminder.Dismiss` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869129.aspx) requires that a reminder (not sure if it has to be the same one) is already displayed in the reminder dialog. That's why this is not working. That said, AFAIK there's no guarantee that `Reminders(1)` will be the reminder that just fired; you may be trying to dismiss the wrong reminder.

As a possible solution (which I must emphasize, *I have not tested*), try using `Reminders.Remove(Item.Subject)`. The documentation seems to indicate that [`Reminders.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869041.aspx) requires the numerical index, but it's worth a try. Also, if two items with reminders have the same subject, there's no guarantee that you'll get the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue myself. j_foster's idea seems to work well. However it's better to use the Entry ID of the appointment item to identify the index of the notification. Then one can use `remove()`.

See below:

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is AppointmentItem Then
        'Do Something...

        'Loop over all reminders and find index of appt
        Dim appt As AppointmentItem: Set appt = Item
        Dim i As Integer: i = 0
        Dim notif As reminder
        For Each notif In Application.Reminders
            i = i + 1
            If notif.Item.EntryID = appt.EntryID Then
                Call Application.Reminders.Remove(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @j_foster Sancarn, applied your code but it crashed (closes outlook) when it comes to line `Call Application.Reminders.Remove(i)`.  Any idea ?

Comment: On the other hand, notification's entryID does not have exact match with appointment's entryID.  Only first 44 characters are the same.  Rest of chars are different, so they dont match.

Comment: I hadn't had this issue before and I'm not sure what could be causing the crash nor the entryID being different :/